# Errors with AnimationClip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have these errors on Unity3D in my anime script :

```
Assets\Assets\Scripts\Assembly-CSharp\AnimBg.cs(14,51): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'clip' of 'AnimationClipPlayable.Create(PlayableGraph, AnimationClip)'

Assets\Assets\Scripts\Assembly-CSharp\AnimBg.cs(15,5): error CS1061: 'AnimationClipPlayable' does not contain a definition for 'speed' and no accessible extension method 'speed' accepting a first argument of type 'AnimationClipPlayable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Assets\Scripts\Assembly-CSharp\AnimBg.cs(16,38): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Animations.AnimationClipPlayable' to 'string'
```

The code is shown below:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

// Token: 0x02000002 RID: 2
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class AnimBg : MonoBehaviour
{
AnimationClipPlayable playable;
    // Token: 0x06000002 RID: 2 RVA: 0x00002058 File Offset: 0x00000458
    private void Start()
    {
        AnimationClipPlayable b = AnimationClipPlayable.Create(this.clip);
        b.speed = this.animspeed;
        base.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(b);
    }

    // Token: 0x04000001 RID: 1
    [SerializeField]
    private AnimationClip clip;

    // Token: 0x04000002 RID: 2
    [SerializeField]
    private float animspeed;
}
```

Thanks for your help, because I cannot compile the game and I don't know how to solve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is the line here

```
AnimationClipPlayable b = AnimationClipPlayable.Create(this.clip);
```

AnimationClipPlayable.Create takes in two parameters; a playable graph and a clip.
Your clip is the second parameter but you need to pass through your playable graph as the first parameter.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimationClipPlayable.Create.html) is the Unity Doc's to explain what that function takes in.

Secondly, AnimationClipPlayable does not contain a variable called speed. If you wish to modify the clips speed, you should use the [SetSpeed()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Playables.PlayableExtensions.SetSpeed.html) function.

```
b.SetSpeed(animspeed);
```

Thirdly, Animator does not contain an override function called Play() which takes in a type of PlayableGraph.

It's hard to know what you truly want but if you just want to play an animation on that gameobject, you can do this:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

// Token: 0x02000002 RID: 2
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class AnimBg : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Token: 0x04000001 RID: 1
    [SerializeField]
    private AnimationClip clip;

    // Token: 0x04000002 RID: 2
    [SerializeField]
    private float animspeed;

    private PlayableGraph graph;
    private AnimationClipPlayable playable;
    private AnimationMixerPlayable mixer;
    // Token: 0x06000002 RID: 2 RVA: 0x00002058 File Offset: 0x00000458
    private void Start()
    {
        graph = PlayableGraph.Create();
        AnimationClipPlayable b = AnimationClipPlayable.Create(graph, clip);
        b.SetSpeed(animspeed);

        mixer = AnimationMixerPlayable.Create (graph);
        mixer.ConnectInput (0, b, 0);
        mixer.SetInputWeight (0, 1);

        var output = AnimationPlayableOutput.Create (graph, "output", GetComponent<Animator> ());
        output.SetSourcePlayable (mixer);
        graph.Play ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @laurent47 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.